# How to fix "Try avoiding to initialize the class that caused initialization" with GraalVM native-image

Tags: java, jar, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to create a native-image from a fat jar file with

```
$ native-image -H:+TraceClassInitialization --initialize-at-run-time=org.slf4j,org.apache.log4j \
               -jar ./my-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

And I'm getting those error messages like:

> Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized
>   during image building:  org.apache.log4j.Level the class was requested
>   to be initialized at build time (from the command line).
>   org.apache.log4j.Level has been initialized without the native-image
>   initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't be tracked.
>   Try avoiding to initialize the class that caused initialization of
>   org.apache.log4j.Level org.slf4j.log4j12.Log4jLoggerAdapter the class
>   was requested to be initialized at build time (from the command line).
>   org.slf4j.log4j12.Log4jLoggerAdapter has been initialized without the
>   native-image initialization instrumentation and the stack trace can't
>   be tracked. Try avoiding to initialize the class that caused
>   initialization of org.slf4j.log4j12.Log4jLoggerAdapter
>   org.apache.log4j.Logger the class was requested to be initialized at
>   build time (from the command line). org.apache.log4j.Logger has been
>   initialized without the native-image initialization instrumentation
>   and the stack trace can't be tracked. Try avoiding to initialize the
>   class that caused initialization of org.apache.log4j.Logger

What are the ways and approaches to `avoiding to initialize the class` issues? How can I deal with those messages?

My graavlVM version is 2.0.0-java11

Answer (score 13):

These steps work for me. I've tried using slf4j and logback, log4j2 but the one that finally works is [slf4j-simple](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/2.0.0-alpha1).
Basically I try to include specific classes that trigger the initialization in `--initialize-at-build-time`.
Here's what I do.

- Add parameter `-H:+TraceClassInitialization` on the build command, like this:

```
native-image -jar my-app.jar 
-H:IncludeResources=".*.xml|.*.conf" 
-H:+ReportUnsupportedElementsAtRuntime 
-H:+TraceClassInitialization 
-H:Name=my-app
--verbose
```

- Run it, you will see some error like this:

```
Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger was unintentionally initialized at build time. io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
        at org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger.<clinit>(SimpleLogger.java) // THIS IS THE OFFENDING CLASS
        at org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLoggerFactory.<init>(SimpleLoggerFactory.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider.initialize(SimpleServiceProvider.java:43)
```

- You see the one line I marked. That is the class to be included.
- Next run the same command with extra parameter `--initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger`
- Run it. You may need to repeat all the above steps as there could be more errors showing up. If so add the classes, separate them with commas.

In my case the final command looks like this

```
native-image -jar my-app.jar 
-H:IncludeResources=".*.xml|.*.conf" 
-H:+ReportUnsupportedElementsAtRuntime 
-H:+TraceClassInitialization 
--initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger,org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
-H:Name=my-app
--verbose
```

Comment: Error: Non-boolean option 'TraceClassInitialization' can not use +/- prefix. Use 'TraceClassInitialization=<value>' format
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception

Comment: Use -H:TraceClassInitialization=true instead

Comment: The error is saying that the class requested to be initialized at runtime but got initialized at build time. Why is the fix to set the class to initialize at build time? Isn't that what caused the exception in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

Here's the full list of classes to exclude if you're using Slf4J and Logback:

```
--initialize-at-build-time=\
org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder\
,org.slf4j.LoggerFactory\
,ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger\
,ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl\
,ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusBase\
,ch.qos.logback.classic.Level\
,ch.qos.logback.core.status.InfoStatus\
,ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout\
,ch.qos.logback.core.CoreConstants
```

Comment: It is not helpful. I'm asking about approaches to resolving that kind of issues

Comment: This _is_ the approach. You don't get to control static class initialization that's used in older-school Java libraries (logging, JDBC, etc.) You can ask the GraalVM team for more details: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues.

Comment: This resulted in a lot of `Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building` related to `com.sun.org.apache.xerces`. Seems that only `slf4j-simple` works for now.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to trace what is the class that cause the "build time initialization" of the classes *org.apache.log4j.Level* and *org.slf4j.log4j12.Log4jLoggerAdapter*.
To do this add the following option to the native-image command:

```
--trace-class-initialization=org.apache.log4j.Level,org.slf4j.log4j12.Log4jLoggerAdapter
```

running the build again you should see somehing like this:

```
 Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
 org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger was unintentionally initialized at build time. **io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel** caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
        at org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger.<clinit>(SimpleLogger.java) 
        at org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLoggerFactory.<init>(SimpleLoggerFactory.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider.initialize(SimpleServiceProvider.java:43)
[...]
```

The important info is just: "org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger was unintentionally initialized at build time. **io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel** caused initialization of this class"

So the solution is to prevent the build-time initialization of the *io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel* class (in the example above, but you have to run the command for your own project to see what is the class that cause the problem). To do this add the following option to the native-image command:

```
--initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel
```

You may need to repeat these steps more times if more errors will be presented.