# Gluon mobile for a Spring application : ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger initialisation

Tags: spring, gradle, logback, gluon-mobile, gluonfx

I have a JavaFX application that is based on Spring Framework. I'm trying to make it working as an Android application.

I'm using gradle and so the gluonfx-gradle-plugin. (v 1.0.18)

When running the nativeCompile task, I get the following error :

> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: **com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. Object has been initialized by the io.netty.util.NetUtil class initializer with a trace:**

> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.(Logger.java:105)
> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]   at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.createChildByName(Logger.java:360)
> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]   at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getLogger(LoggerContext.java:156)
> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]   at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getLogger(LoggerContext.java:54)
> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]   at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:391)
> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]   at io.netty.util.internal.logging.Slf4JLoggerFactory.newInstance(Slf4JLoggerFactory.java:49)
> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]   at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(InternalLoggerFactory.java:134)
> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]   at io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(InternalLoggerFactory.java:127)
> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]   at io.netty.util.NetUtilInitializations.(NetUtilInitializations.java:38)
> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB]   at io.netty.util.NetUtil.(NetUtil.java:145)

> [mer. avr. 19 15:21:06 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB] .  **To fix the issue mark ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger for build-time initialization with --initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger or use the the information from the trace to find the culprit and --initialize-at-run-time= to prevent its instantiation.**

I have tried to solve the problem adding this block in gluonfx block of the build.gradle :

```
gluonfx {
  ...
    compilerArgs = ["--trace-object-instantiation=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger",
                    "--initialize-at-run-time=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger"
    ]
  ...
}
```

But this doesn't produce any change on the nativeCompile result.

In addition to this problem.
I have a lot of Warning :

> [mer. avr. 19 15:33:19 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Could not register io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Lz4FrameDecoder: queryAllPublicMethods for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jpountz/lz4/LZ4Exception.
> [mer. avr. 19 15:33:19 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Could not register io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Lz4FrameDecoder: queryAllPublicMethods for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jpountz/lz4/LZ4Exception.
> [mer. avr. 19 15:33:19 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Could not register io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Lz4FrameEncoder: queryAllPublicMethods for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jpountz/lz4/LZ4Exception.
> [mer. avr. 19 15:33:19 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Could not register io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Lz4FrameEncoder: queryAllPublicMethods for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jpountz/lz4/LZ4Exception.
> [mer. avr. 19 15:33:19 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB] Warning: Could not register io.netty.handler.codec.marshalling.CompatibleMarshallingDecoder: queryAllPublicMethods for reflection. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/marshalling/ByteInput.
> ...

Are there important ?

Please, can someone give me some guidance to solve this problem ?

Thank you.

**Edit :**

I have solved this problem following this [issue] ([javafx graalvm Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66933202/javafx-graalvm-error-classes-that-should-be-initialized-at-run-time-got-initial)).
For me, what worked was to add in the build.gradle :

```
compilerArgs = ["--trace-object-instantiation=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger",
            "--allow-incomplete-classpath",
            "--initialize-at-run-time=io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4JLogger"]
```

And the file resources/META-INF/substrate/config/initbuildtime with the following content :

```
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
org.slf4j.simple.SimpleLogger
org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl
ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusBase
ch.qos.logback.classic.Level
ch.qos.logback.core.status.InfoStatus
ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout
ch.qos.logback.core.CoreConstants
org.slf4j.MDC
ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter
ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader
```

Doing this, I can create the executable (nativeLink).

But when running the application with nativeRun, the application stop immediately with the following error :

> [mer. avr. 19 18:29:00 CEST 2023][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.DefaultFlowMessageFactory.()

I'm using @Log4J2 with lombok. It seems something was not correctly compiled.

Comment: Without a test case to reproduce the issue, it is really hard to say. There are some Log4J2 issues that might be of some help: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/808 or https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2649

Comment: Hi Jose, 
I will try to prepare you a simple example that reproduce the problem. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jose, 

You will find a sample here with the problem : 
https://github.com/guirak/GluonWithSpring

I have created 2 branches : 
- [1_logbackUnsupportedFeatureException](https://github.com/guirak/GluonWithSpring/tree/1_logbackUnsupportedFeatureException) : this branch reproduces the build problem that I have with the logger.
- [2_log4j_missing_class](https://github.com/guirak/GluonWithSpring/tree/2_log4j_missing_class): this branch contains 1 additional commit that permits to finish the build without error but when starting, I fall in a NoSuchMethodException.