# GraalVM (native-image) can not compile logback dependencies

Tags: java, logback, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm using the current version of community edition: GraalVM/native-image 22.1.0

My project has a dependency to the logging framework logback (version 1.2.3)

If I want to compile my "all-in-one" jar with graalVM the native-image complains:

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No
> instances of ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger are allowed in the image
> heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. To see how
> this object got instantiated use
> --trace-object-instantiation=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.

I played around with many different permutations of settings e.g. `--initialize-at-run-time=\<complete list of logback classes\>`  and `--initialize-at-run-time`

I tried to generate a reflection configuration file with

`java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=META-INF/native-image -jar build/myjar-all.jar`

and added it to the config file with

`-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflect-config.json`

But without success. Always getting different error messages all related to logback.

So my question:

**Has anyone got logback successfully compiled with graalvm before?**

Comment: Have you tried changing the loggers in your code from static to normal fields? It is common to use static loggers with logback, but not required. If you use "private final Logger" instead of "private static final Logger" the initialization will happen at runtime. EDIT: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654455/how-to-fix-try-avoiding-to-initialize-the-class-that-caused-initialization-wit?rq=1.

Answer (score 26):

Short answer - you should add `ch.qos.logback` to `--initialize-at-build-time`:

```
--initialize-at-build-time=ch.qos.logback
```

For details, I would like to post what I have done to make `logback` working with GraalVM.

In the `build.gradle` file, I added instructions about what should be included at build time, at run time and also path to the file contains reflection configuration:

```
graalvmNative {
  binaries {
    all {
      resources.autodetect()
    }
    main {
      imageName.set('app') 
      buildArgs.add('--verbose')
      buildArgs.add('--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED')
      buildArgs.add('--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED')
      buildArgs.add('--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED')
      buildArgs.add('--trace-class-initialization=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger')
      buildArgs.add('--trace-object-instantiation=ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase$Worker')
      buildArgs.add('--initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.LoggerFactory,ch.qos.logback')
      buildArgs.add('--initialize-at-run-time=io.netty')
    }
  }
}

nativeBuild {
  buildArgs('-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=../../../src/main/resources/reflection-config.json')
}
```

Here is the content of `reflection-config.json` file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.DateConverter",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.LevelConverter",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.LineSeparatorConverter",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.LoggerConverter",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.MessageConverter",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ThreadConverter",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  },
  {
    "name": "ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "allDeclaredClasses": true,
    "allPublicClasses": true
  }
]
```

I use this `logback.xml` file:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="150 seconds">
  <property name="LOG_DIR" value="logs" />

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" target="System.out">
    <encoder>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", UTC} {%thread} [%-5level] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_DIR}/app.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <charset>UTF-8</charset>
      <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", UTC} {%thread} [%-5level] %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNC_CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold> <!-- default 20, means drop lower event when has 20% capacity remaining -->
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <queueSize>1024</queueSize> <!-- default 256 -->
    <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData> <!-- default false -->
    <neverBlock>false</neverBlock> <!-- default false, set to true to cause the Appender not block the application and just drop the messages -->
  </appender>

  <appender name="ASYNC_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold> <!-- default 20, means drop lower event when has 20% capacity remaining -->
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <queueSize>1024</queueSize> <!-- default 256 -->
    <includeCallerData>false</includeCallerData> <!-- default false -->
    <neverBlock>false</neverBlock> <!-- default false, set to true to cause the Appender not block the application and just drop the messages -->
  </appender>

  <root level="all">
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have exacly the same problem, but when a add `graalvmNative` it doesn't change anything, it looks like the block is completely ignored, even when I include `--verbose` or `--trace-object-instantiation=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger`, any ideas?

Comment: It's exactly the same to me @VitorRamos. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: To me it looks like a general problem in the combination of Spring Native and logsstash: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33758

Comment: @RolfNyffenegger since I noticed that the whole block was ignored, I thought it could be a problem with the gradle plugin, so I tried using maven with the build arg and it worked.

Comment: In some cases, you may also want to add `-H:IncludeResources=logback.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late to answer but this may help someone. I was also facing issues with `logback.xml` initialisation.

While searching for solution I found that spring suggests to name the file as `logback-spring.xml` instead of `logback.xml`

See here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

[image]