# Native Image with Spring Boot 3.0.0 logging trouble

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, spring-native

When I start native Image of Spring Boot 3.0.0 spring-boot-starter-web with Docker, it shows strange log messages like this:

`:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.0)`
`%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 --- [%PARSER_ERROR[t]] %PARSER_ERROR[logger] : %PARSER_ERROR[m]%PARSER_ERROR[n]%PARSER_ERROR[d] %PARSER_ERROR[p] 1 ---`

Before I tried dependency spring-boot-starter-webflux in this case the build of the native image failed with error:
`com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger are allowed in the image heap`

With Spring Initializr I generated a new project:

- Maven
- Java 17
- Spring Boot version 3.0.0
- Jar
- Dependencies: spring-boot-starter-web & lombok

Then I build native Image with Maven "mvn -p native spring-boot:build-image".

I had the expectation, that native Images just work with the new Spring release for simple configuration like the one I made here. Am I missing something or has Spring Boot 3.0.0 big issues in supporting native Images?

Comment: You should check the reason for this: `com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger are allowed in the image heap` ??

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72770461/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time when I asked this question, Spring Initializr did not offer (plugin-)dependency "GraalVM Native Support" for Spring Boot 3.0.0.

Now this dependency is available. As confirmed at SpringOne event, it has to be used. After adding it the mentioned errors do not appear. The minimal required part in Maven config is this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
  <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you add reachability of metadata goal in your build plugin see github i[ssue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33432)

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
  <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
    <metadataRepository>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </metadataRepository>
    <requiredVersion>22.3</requiredVersion>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>add-reachability-metadata</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>add-reachability-metadata</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```