# Spring Boot / GraalVM native-maven-plugin failing with runtime vs build-time class initialization

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to build a native image using Spring Boot 3, referring to [these docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#native-image-options).

I'm hitting the below exception at build time:

```
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
[INFO]     [creator]      ch.qos.logback.core.status.InfoStatus was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why ch.qos.logback.core.status.InfoStatus got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=ch.qos.logback.core.status.InfoStatus
[INFO]     [creator]     ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader
[INFO]     [creator]     ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
[INFO]     [creator]     ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter
[INFO]     [creator]     ch.qos.logback.classic.Level was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why ch.qos.logback.classic.Level got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=ch.qos.logback.classic.Level
[INFO]     [creator]     ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusBase was unintentionally initialized at build time. To see why ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusBase got initialized use --trace-class-initialization=ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusBase
[INFO]     [creator]     To see how the classes got initialized, use --trace-class-initialization=ch.qos.logback.core.status.InfoStatus,ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader,ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger,ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter,ch.qos.logback.classic.Level,ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusBase
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
[INFO]     [creator]     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     [creator]         1.6s (3.8% of total time) in 25 GCs | Peak RSS: 5.87GB | CPU load: 4.39
```

Based on [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66461706/59015), I've configured the maven plugin as follows, but it hasn't had any effect:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
   <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
      <metadataRepository>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
      </metadataRepository>
      <requiredVersion>22.3</requiredVersion>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
      <!-- note: I've tried several combinations of combine.children here, including omitting it entirely, none seem to have any effect -->

      <buildArgs>
         <arg>--verbose</arg>
         <arg>--initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.LoggerFactory,ch.qos.logback</arg>
         <arg>--trace-class-initialization=ch.qos.logback.core.status.InfoStatus,ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter,ch.qos.logback.classic.Level,ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger,ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader,ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusBase</arg>
      </buildArgs>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My POM inherits from `spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.2` :

```xml
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
```

I've tried multiple different configurations, but I can't seem to change the exception.

I note that adding `-H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces` had no impact, so I'm wondering if I'm passing these args incorrectly?

How do I correctly configure the maven plugin to remove these errors?

Comment: Remove `<arg>--initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.LoggerFactory,ch.qos.logback</arg>` from plugin in pom.xml. This is initializing both of those classes at build time which is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't have an impact - in fact I added that specifically because of this problem - based on answers from others having similar issues (see linked question)

Comment: This was answered in my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78080091/how-to-correctly-pass-initialize-at-build-time-trace-class-initialization-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of digging, the specific issue turns out to be an old slf4j driver in a transient dependency (snowflake-jdbc), which is shaded in.

[Here](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/issues/1310)'s the relevant issue.

After removing the dependency on snowflake, native builds worked again.